# How to connect pgadmin with google cloud postgres with ssl certificates

Tags: postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect to google cloud's postgres with ssl certificates. I have pgadmin application locally. I tried connecting by setting my ip addess in allow netwroks and it worked. But, If I emove that settinging and tried with SSL certificates its not working.

I tried all ssl modes (sllow,require, verifiy-CA,verfy-full) . But, none of these works. please help me.

Comment: If you don't allow your network to connect, then you can't connect. SSL doesn't offer a way around this.  SSH might offer a way, through tunneling, but that would be a different topic.

Comment: Yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

As @jjanes said it  seems like its not possible. so, I allowed to every ip address 0.0.0.0/0 and allowed connection only with ssl certificates. This worked for me.